# No client is generated with StrawberryShake

Tags: .net, graphql, strawberryshake

I am using  Strawberry Shake
The schema seems to be generated just fine
[image]

When i build i dont see any generated folder .  Seems there is no client generated .
I am doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and found the solution on this page:
https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2021/10/graphqlstrawberry-shake-graphql-client.html

First, your screenshot shows no query created. You need first to create a query file, like for example AddMovieData.graphql

query FetchGenreList{
genreList{
genreId,
genreName
}
}

You need to edit the properties of AddMovieData.graphql and set the build action for the graphql file to GraphQL compiler.

Cheers

Comment: Any idea why the GraphQL Compiler does show up in the build actions? Is there another package that needs to be installed?

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Fuzzycheck's response. I encountered an issue where I couldn't set the build action to GraphQL Compiler. You can get around this by going into the .csproj file and adding:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="GraphQL\AddMovieData.graphql">
        <Generator>MSBuild:GenerateGraphQLCode</Generator>
    </None>
<ItemGroup>
```

I noticed this is an issue with VS2022. With Rider it generates the right code in the csproj and generates the graphql c# code.